# How do I add auth to and deploy my React app with lambda api?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, authentication, serverless

I have locally working code for a React front-end application, hooked up to a [serverless framework](https://www.serverless.com/) lambda back-end (which in turn accesses S3 and RDS). I'm now at the stage where I need to add user authentication to both the front and back-end, as well as deploy my solution.

I have cobbled together a Cloudfront distribution and s3 static hosting for the React portion, with the api available as a secondary origin on `/api/*`, however this solution seems awkward, and I'm not sure it helps me tackle auth.

Other guides that I've found suggest AWS-Amplify, or [SST](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/what-is-sst.html), but I have no experience with either.

Am I close to a well-structured roll-your-own solution, or completely on the wrong track? I'm happy to spend a little longer on a clean and future-proof solution, but am not adverse to side-stepping to a well respected tool.

Comment: If you want to stick with AWS, then check out Cognito. If you want to look outside the AWS service offering check out Auth0.

Comment: Yea, Cognito looks like the clear choice. Just trying to figure out how to incorporate it with react and the serverless side of things without the lot getting ugly

Comment: With Amplify its very straight forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted to follow [this guide on SST](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/what-is-sst.html). Once I saw it did everything I could have wanted and more, I ported over my API and React code with minimal fuss. I wouldn't hesitate to recommend this guide (which leverages SST, Amplify and Cognito).